# installing numpy using pip freezing

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I need to install Numpy version 1.17.1, but every time it just freezes. I have now tried multiple times and I have been waiting over 25 min seeing the same screen.
[image: installation image]
Is this a known issue or am I facing an issue with installing?

The OS that I'm using is Ubuntu on my raspberry pi 3.

Comment: try the absolute path for `pip3`? - usually, `usr/bin/` (I think)

Comment: @AnthonyR yes, pip3 is in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: For clarity: `/usr/bin/pip3 install numpy` didn't work?

Comment: @AnthonyR I haven't tried that yet. Currently, I'm trying to run it as `sudo pip3 install numpy==1.17.1 --force` as andopr suggested. I'm in the /urs/bin/ directory, I'm not sure if that is the same as you suggested. But that has been running for about 10 min now, so I fear that also doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The long delay is because `numpy` is being compiled on your Raspberry Pi. To see what is happening under the hood, you can run `pip3` with `--verbose`.

```
$ pip3 install --verbose numpy==1.17.1
```

This will give you a better understanding of the problem you are seeing.

To solve that, I would recommend adding https://www.piwheels.org as an extra index for packages so that you can obtain pre-compiled [wheels](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) on your Raspberry Pi, saving you a lot of time.

In order to add an extra index globally on your system, all you need to do is edit (or create) a file `/etc/pip.conf` with the following contents:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

After that, you should see something like:

```
$ pip3 install numpy==1.17.1
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting numpy==1.17.1
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/numpy-1.17.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl (10.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.5MB 7.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.1
```

Note: tested on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: I have added the lines to `/etc/pip.conf`, but pip is still using `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/79/96df883cd6df0c86cb010e6f4ff790b7a30a45016a9509c94ea72c8695cd/numpy-1.17.1.zip`

can I force pip to use the pip.conf settings?

Comment: In case it says "Using cached...." try to run pip with `--no-cache-dir`. Your cache is located at `~/.cache/pip`.

Comment: I ran `pip3 install numpy==1.17.1 --no-cache-dir` and now its not `using cache` but downloading from `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/79/96df883cd6df0c86cb010e6f4ff790b7a30a45016a9509c94ea72c8695cd/numpy-1.17.1.zip` and not using the piwheels

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the specific Python version you have? the output of `python --version`.

Comment: I have python 3.6.8

Comment: Ok. Sorry I forgot to mention that not all versions of Python are covered for all packages. Numpy for example (https://www.piwheels.org/project/numpy/) is offered for Python 3.5 (cp35m) and 3.7 (cp37m). If you can upgrade to 3.7, you can use the answer above. Otherwise you will really need to compile. (Latest Raspbian includes Python 3.7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198679/discussion-between-wes-and-leandro-n).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute the command with sudo.

Comment: I don't see why that will work since I have installed about 20 other packages without it. But I will try

Comment: Sure :) What about trying an alternative installation method like: 'sudo apt-get install python3-numpy' ? If it's a dependencies problem this should download everything else it needs.

Comment: @andorp I tried but ubuntu gave me an error: `E: Unable to locate package numpy`