# Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Numpy Pip Install Fails

Tags: python, numpy, pip, raspberry-pi, virtualenv

New to raspberry pi.

I have a raspberry pi zero 2 w, and I am trying to pip install numpy in a virtual environment. After a few minutes of waiting, the pi freezes. I waited for 2.5 hours, and the pi didn't unfreeze or finish installing numpy. I am using Python 3.7.3, and I have checked that my pip.conf file contained the line needed to use piwheels as shown in this thread:

[installing numpy using pip freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715216/installing-numpy-using-pip-freezing)

It seems as if other people have encountered this issue, but were unable to identify a solution, as discussed in this thread:

https://klipper.discourse.group/t/trouble-installing-numpy-on-pi-zero-2w/1458

Here is what I am typing into/seeing in the command prompt:
[image]

The pi freezes a few minutes into "running setup.py".

Pip installing other libraries, such as pyserial, works fine. But installing libraries which require numpy (such as matplotlib) also fails.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never been able to compile numpy in RPi zero, try apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```

and/or

```
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: Be aware that apt versions are different to pip